# How do I remove remote git server from local repository

Tags: git

Hi I have a git repository pulled local from github.com, how do I remove the github.com remove server and just keep the local git server (i.e last 2 lines)

```
youInside   https://github.com/youInside/rpi-configs (fetch)
youInside   https://github.com/youInside/rpi-configs (push)
origin  https://github.com/sanfx/rpi-configs.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/sanfx/rpi-configs.git (push)
pi  git@192.168.1.2:/home/git/rpi-configs (fetch)
pi  git@192.168.1.2:/home/git/rpi-configs (push)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List your remotes

```
  git remote -v
```

remove your remote

```
  git remote remove origin
```

Origin should be the remote name

Answer (score 1):

```
git remote remove origin
git remote remove youInside
```

should work.